# embedded-jmxtrans - Need to export metrics on Influx-Grafana

Tags: jmx, jmxtrans

I don't see influxDB outputwriter in embedded-jmxtrans but i see it in jmxtrans , we are using embedded-jmxtrans for our scala code based docker container JVM metrics , is there a way we can acheive this ?